# in nueral network , WX+B is linear transformation?

Tags: deep-learning, linear-algebra

in linear algebra, linear function is called linear transformation

in neural network ,

[linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) need two condition

1. `f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)`
2. `f(cx) = cf(x)`

but `WX+B` is not satisfied these two condition. So, this is my question,
even `wx+b` isn't satisfied above two condition, but normally people call `wx + b` to linear function. why?

thank you. master

Comment: Wx + b is affine-linear (linear + constant). Most people are probably just too lazy to note the difference (since it often doesn't really matter).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is to clarify mathematical terminology, not a programming tool.  Also, the question is easily answered with a careful reading of the available research results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linear function and linear transform are two different concepts.

Comment: thank you @Eric Yu , but wikidepia said a [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) is a [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) , and linear map is [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map), 
So What's the difference linear function and linear map?

Comment: wikidepia says a linear function AS a linear map, not IS a linear map

Comment: thankyou, @Eric Yu but at [linear function page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) wiki also 
said  *'In linear algebra, a linear function is a map'* and [at linear map page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) , wiki said *'In mathematics, a linear map (also called a linear mapping, linear transformation or, in some contexts, linear function) is a mapping '*

Answer (score 0):

there are different concept:

1. linear transformer:y=wx
2. affine transformer:y=wx+b